# Android: Options button missing android studio

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

In Android Studio, I am hiding the title bar, now I cant see options (3 dots) button in navigation bar.

What should I do to make it appear in navigation bar, like (in eclipse, by default opt btn will be added to the navigation bar).

I want to display options btn in my device for my app when title bar is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the action `show toolbar` by opening the action popup with that shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+A/ ⌘ + Shift + A` depending on which OS your on. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually my question is I want to display options btn in my device for my app when title bar is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unfamiliar with using **`Android Studio`** interface, [Android Studio Tips and Tricks](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html) page provides some tips to help you get started with some of the most common tasks and productivity enhancements.

Please check this tutorials .I hope it will helps you .